# Rational number computational model

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computability, rational-numbers, computational-mathematics

I need a reference to a paper that says if a problem is easy to solve then it is also easy to solve on a machine in which every piece of data is a rational number to any precision and $+,-,\cdot, \div$ are all $O(1)$ operations.  With possibly more operations allowed, whatever they think is appropriate.  Seems obvious though.  If I wrote a paper, would I have to say anything more than that?

Comment: Define `easy to solve` and `more operations allowed`.

Comment: The first "easy to solve" is on what kind of machine?  And what constitutes "easy"?

Comment: There are algorithms that may cause spectacular coefficient blow-up when performed over the rational numbers; an example that comes to mind is $\gcd$ of univariate polynomials using Euclid's algorithm. I therefore doubt the statement you make is true.